Spring Boot+datastore throws "Type must not be Null" when JsonNode is used as attribute on a Datastore Entity
I been working on a spring boot project which use Datastore as backend. On this project, I'm trying to update jackson dependencies from the current version it has (2.13.4) to a newer one (2.16.2) but I'm getting an error on bean creation which only says "Type must not be null".

After a lot of debugging, and creating a SpringBoot+Datastore project from scratch, I found that if I remove a JsonNode attribute from a Datastore Entity the service starts and beans can be created.
As this error has happened after I upgraded Jackson dependencies I feel there's a missing dependency or configuration which could be required but after checking Spring Cloud Datastore and Jackson documentation and release notes but so far no luck.
Has any of you had to deal with this kind od error or some similar who can guide me on this error?
I made a sample Spring Boot project to replicate the error. This has only 4 classes, just enough to launch a Spring Boot project which use one DatastoreRepository and a Datastore Entity, which has a JsonNode attribute. It doesn't have any additional logic and, if we setup jackson version to 2.13.4 it starts.
Here is the demo project: https://github.com/jevanio/demoProject
Note: As it was build with Java 17, to start the project on local it's required to include as Environment Variable JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS=--add-opens java.base/java.math=ALL-UNNAMED to fix a math library error

I tried to upgrade jackson dependency to 2.14.X or higher but the project doesn't start. I'm getting Type must not be null as error

It seems JsonNode can't be null in the entity instance. Try this: JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().createObjectNode(); 

@hhrzc I tried to instantiate JsonNode on the entity as object mapper but it give the same error :/
